# Смещается картинка в Launch Screen во время включения «режима модема»

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, при включённом режиме модема на устройстве, смещается картинка на стартовом экране приложения. В storyboard картинка выставлена по центру view, зафиксирован ее размер. 
Что я ещё упустил?
[image: режим модема включён]
[image: режим модема выключен]

Comment: Добро пожаловать на SO. Прикрепляйте изобраения не таких огромных размеров. Достаточно изображений небольших размеров, но на которых видна проблема.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению, у этой проблемы только одно решение. В info.plist необходимо прописать:

```
Status bar is initially hidden YES
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы скрыть статус бар на момент запуска.

Если посмотрите, то у многих приложений такая же проблема:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Решение работает